# How to define statics in React es6 component?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to define statics in React es6 component. I know how its done for below component

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  statics: {
    customMethod: function(foo) {
      return foo === 'bar';
    }
  },
  render: function() {
  }
});
```

But want same for a react component defined as below

```
class MyComponent extends Component{ ... }
```

Also I want to call that method from the place where `MyComponent` is going to be instantiated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can **use the `static` keyword** to create static member variables in ES6 classes:

```
class StaticMethodCall {
    static staticMethod() {
        return 'Static method has been called';
    }
    static anotherStaticMethod() {
        return this.staticMethod() + ' from another static method';
    }
}
StaticMethodCall.staticMethod(); 
// 'Static method has been called'

StaticMethodCall.anotherStaticMethod(); 
// 'Static method has been called from another static method'
```

[Source and more info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)